# How to test a chart to see if it renders correctly

Tags: jestjs

I need help, I wanted to test whether the graph is rendering to me by searching for the word that should appear after the graph is rendered, but it gets an error.
I am trying to write tests in JEST
Below is a function drawing a graph

```
export interface CharProps {
    data:Array<any>,
    labels:Array<any>
}


export const Graph: React.FC<CharProps> = ({labels,data}) => {
    const [chartData, setChartData]= useState({})
    const chart = ()=>{
        setChartData({
            labels:labels,
          datasets:[
            {
                label: 'Annual revenue',
                fill: false,
               
            }
        ]
        })
      }
      
      useEffect(()=>{
        chart()
      },[])
      
        return (
            
            <>
            <div className={chartBackground}>
            <Line data={chartData} options={{responsive:true}}/> 
          </div>
          </>
        );
}
```

And my test below

```
describe('<Graph /> ', () => {
    it('should be redner', () => {    
        render(<Graph data={[65]} labels={['monday']} ></Graph>);
        expect(screen.getByText('monday')).toBeTruthy;
    });
})
```

And my bug

```
 TypeError: Cannot set property '_options' of undefined

       8 | describe('<Graph /> ', () => {
       9 |     it('should be redner', () => {
    > 10 |         render(<Graph data={[65]} labels={['monday']} ></Graph>);
         |         ^
      11 |         expect(screen.getByText('monday')).toBeTruthy;
      12 |     });
      13 | })
```

I cannot understand it, please help.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited context available I can only guess what the problem is. But it seems like Graph is unknown to jest. Please check if you have properly imported the Graph component in your test file or test helper.

More information on jest and react: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react